# Django message box while view is running

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django app which performs a rather time consuming statistical model run within my `views.py`.

As the computation progresses in the `view` I would like to inform the user perdiodically before the final `HttpResponse`, for e.g.:

```
Step 1 completed
Step 2 running...
```

Is there a way to display a message to the front-end while the `view` is running?

Answer (score 1):

Long-running tasks should be executed asynchronously. You can use [dango-celery](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery/) for async tasks, then from your view start the task and redirect a user to the page where you can display progress. From your celery task, you can update a progress value as well.

```
class Job(models.Model):
   ...
   progress = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
   ...
```

If you want to display progress value dynamically, then you need an API or at least a view which you will hit by ajax. Something like this:

```
def progres_view(request, job_id):
    value = 0
    try:
        job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    except Job.DoesNotExist:
        job = None
    if job is not None:
        value = job.progress
    response = {"job": job_id, "progress": value}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```